# Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule' angular js 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to use Owl Carousel slider in my Angular page. I have installed Owl Carousel and imported all needed code. However, I get this error when I run the file:

> Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule' angular js 6

Can anyone kindly find the error for me?

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {OwlCarousel} from 'angular-owl-carousel2';
import { SlickModule } from 'ngx-slick';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
      OwlCarousel,
      SlickModule.forRoot()
      //RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: `angular-owl-carousel2` is used with Angular 1 for Angular I think you need [ngx-owl-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel)

Comment: ok thanks i will try